# Covariance matrix in nonlinear pca (eqn)..Why is it different from linear pca...?

Tags: data-mining, pca

I have been reading some of the kernel PCA(KPCA) related papers...I am not clear with the concepts yet...

I have found that "covariance matrix" is found by taking transpose in KPCA which is not the case in  linear pca..Why is this difference(in equation) when it is said that KPCA is similar to PCA exempting that before finding the covariance matrix and proceeding with the eigen value ,eigen vector things there needs a mapping to be done(in KPCA)..?I also know in KPCA the input is mapped to a high dimension feature space using the kernel trick.I am confused with the covariance part.

Please help..

Comment: @LEP : I am now going through the paper **http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Kernel/kernelPCA_scholkopf.pdf ...

** ...It's said that PCA diagonalizes the covariance matrix...How and why?

Answer (score 0):

The determination of the covariance matrix in KPCA is straightforward -- so there are no questions about its relationship with PCA.  Search for the Gram matrix, and you will then understand.  By the way, also search on "non-linear manifold learning" or "distance metric learning" and in both you will obtain full details about KPCA.  It sounds like you haven't studied radial basis function (RBF) kernels enough to fully understand what is going on.  So search on RBF kernels, which also happen to be employed in Kernel Regression and Support Vector Machines.

Comment: I am quite a newbie to kpca...Thanks for the reply and references..!

Comment: I have realized the transpose thing is similar to the normal equation of PCA (ie by finding out the mean and then subtracting from datapoints)..and in kpca its just represented using the transpose equation..(the answer of both wud be the same).. :)